# Ensure dog always has a clean backside

Tags: dogs, furniture

Doubt there's an answer for this but I really hope so.

Basically, I've always thought it strange (but convenient) how when a dog sits on a carpet or furniture or something, he doesn't leave any fecal remnants.

However, today my dog sat in the passenger seat, and for whatever reason left some slight (very slight, only noticeable if you were looking) smears on the seat.

I love it when my dog jumps up onto my bed and paws me awake (he doesn't run riot around the house, but he his allowed to do this) but now I'm just really paranoid he's going to leave fecal marks behind.

Like I say, I doubt there's an answer other than keeping him completely off the furniture, but is there a way, diet wise or whatever to ensure he's clean? **I mean, cats never seem to have this problem.** He's a Border Collie, so he can be trained.

I guess this is why pets aren't often allowed on the furniture...

Answer (score 4):

I do not believe there is a specific diet which will ensure that no feces remains on a dog's backside. Having a poor diet might make this problem worse for the dog (due to loose stools or diarrhea), but diet alone will not prevent it.

The alternative that we use is to check our dog's behind after she eliminates and wipe off anything that "hangs out" afterwards. Our dog also expects a treat after using the restroom (we have her trained to use a litterbox in the house), so she will come and find us  to show off her work and we will wipe her up before giving her the treat.
While on walks or outside, we are already keeping a close eye on her to pick up any droppings, so we will inspect and wipe her behind clean at that point if anything remains.

I am not sure if this applies to border collies specifically, but some breeds of dogs and cats will periodically secrete a dark brown, smelly substance from anal glands right next to the main anal opening. The smears might be from this "butt juice" rather than fecal remains, but unfortunately I have not found an effective way to stop those secretions.

Answer (score 4):

You could increase the fiber in the diet just like a human would with this issue. A fiber supplement (food or pills) may reduce the chance of this happening by helping the stools stay firm and not runny.

Also have a vet check to see if the dog is leaking at all, maybe a more significant health issue.

Answer (score 0):

My husband was telling me how a dogs rectum comes out some when they poop so that the outside stays cleaner. I can't even figure out how to google for this so I don't have a reference :( One of the few animals that do this.